# methods for optimising list comprehension or alternatives

Tags: python, list, performance

`list1` contains a list of Indexes roughly 50,000 in length.
`list2` contains a list or words roughly 60,000 in lenght.

I am iteration over the lists using the following list comprehension:

```
newList= [w for w in list2 if list2.index(w) in list1]
```

The problem is that it takes quite a while for this to run, does anyone know any hints tips or tricks to speed up this process, or achieve the same outcome in a faster approach.

I have discovered that turning list1 into a set speeds up the process, but is still slower than I would like

Comment: Can the lists contain duplicates?

Comment: It is highly unlikly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most list operation is O(n). Your list comprehension one-liner is probably O(n^3). So with that in mind, I would suggest to break this into two lines instead of one:

```
indices = set(x for x in list1 if x < len(list2))
newList = [w for i,w in enumerate(list2) if i in indices]
```

The first line extract all indices from `list1` that can possibly included in `list2`. This is to correspond to your clause `list2.index(w) in list1`. The second line is to select those in `list2` that included in the indices set. Using set operation can reduce your search time from O(n) to O(1). Using enumerate can avoid the `list2.index()` call which also reduce O(n) to O(1). This two lines together is running at only O(n) time.

If your `list2` contains duplicates, this will need to change. But still, possible to be O(n):

```
indices = set(x for x in list1 if x < len(list2))
lookup = {}
for i,w in enumerate(list2):
    if w not in lookup:
        lookup[w] = i
newList = [w for w in list2 if lookup[w] in indices]
```

Answer (score 0):

`index()` needs to search through the list to find the index of the item and it only finds the first index of the first item it finds (which is important if there are duplicates). That means this is an `O(n² )` algorithm. Then you search the whole of list1 for it, making it `O(n²  + mn)`. But you already know the index because you are looping over `list2` — there's no reason to search for it. So don't search again just make the indices a set and see if the index you are on is in it. This will be O(n).

```
list2 = ['hello', 'dog', 'cat', 'house']
list1 = set([0, 2, 3])

[w for i, w in enumerate(list2) if i in list1]
#['hello', 'cat', 'house']
```